# Grepping what's not there?

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame`:

```
   pr_id  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9 t10 t11 t12 t13 t14
3  X1818 PID ECV ECV ECV ECV SMK DEC REF SMK                    
4  X2044 PID PRO SMK SMK ECV                                    
5  X1572 PID PRO REF SMK SMK TEA SMK SMK TEA SMK SMK SMK SMK DEC
6  X2030 PID ECV PRO PRO ECV WRC DEC ECV SMK SMK DEC            
7  X2060 PID PRO TEA ECV TEA DEC
```

The `dput` is here:

```
structure(list(pr_id = c("X1626", "X1689", "X1818", "X2044", 
"X1572"), t1 = c("PID", "WRC", "PID", "PID", "PID"), t2 = c("PRO", 
"DEC", "ECV", "PRO", "PRO"), t3 = c("REF", "", "ECV", "SMK", 
"REF"), t4 = c("ECV", "", "ECV", "SMK", "SMK"), t5 = c("SMK", 
"", "ECV", "ECV", "SMK"), t6 = c("SMK", "", "SMK", "", "TEA"), 
t7 = c("DEC", "", "DEC", "", "SMK"), t8 = c("", "", "REF", 
"", "SMK"), t9 = c("", "", "SMK", "", "TEA"), t10 = c("", 
"", "", "", "SMK"), t11 = c("", "", "", "", "SMK"), t12 = c("", 
"", "", "", "SMK"), t13 = c("", "", "", "", "SMK"), t14 = c("", 
"", "", "", "DEC")), .Names = c("pr_id", "t1", "t2", "t3", 
"t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", "t9", "t10", "t11", "t12", "t13", 
"t14"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

...but when I run:

```
df[grep(pattern = "DEC", df, fixed = TRUE),]
```

I get a match for the line with `pr_id` = `X2044`. How is this possible, since it doesn't contain the string `DEC`?

Comment: @akrun: Are you sure? It gets all the other rows properly, it just gets one too many.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: @akrun - all the rows except for the one that has `pr_id` = `X2044`, because it doesn't contain `DEC`

Comment: Your dput does not match the data printed in the first block.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to find extract the rows that have 'DEC' element, one option is to `grep` through the rows with `apply` specifying `MARGIN=1`.  Check whether there is `any` TRUE values from the output of `grepl`, use that as a logical index to subset the rows.

```
 df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(grepl('DEC', x))),]
 #   pr_id  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9 t10 t11 t12 t13 t14
 #1 X1626 PID PRO REF ECV SMK SMK DEC                            
 #2 X1689 WRC DEC                                                
 #3 X1818 PID ECV ECV ECV ECV SMK DEC REF SMK                    
 #5 X1572 PID PRO REF SMK SMK TEA SMK SMK TEA SMK SMK SMK SMK DEC
```

Or another option would be using `==` to output a logical matrix.  Get the `rowSums`.  Negate (`!`) so that if there is 0 'DEC' in a row, it will get converted to `TRUE` and all others as `FALSE`.  We negate (`!`) again to convert the `FALSE` to `TRUE` and viceversa.  This can be used for subsetting.

```
 df[!!rowSums(df=='DEC'),]
 #   pr_id  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9 t10 t11 t12 t13 t14
 #1 X1626 PID PRO REF ECV SMK SMK DEC                            
 #2 X1689 WRC DEC                                                
 #3 X1818 PID ECV ECV ECV ECV SMK DEC REF SMK                    
 #5 X1572 PID PRO REF SMK SMK TEA SMK SMK TEA SMK SMK SMK SMK DEC
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Do you know why my previous command did not work? It doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: @histelheim `grep` works on vectors. A data.frame is a vector of columns. So you are getting the columns in which "DEC" appears, not the rows.